# Add browser tab/desktop notification when user gets notification

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I would like to suggest a Stack Exchange (and all its sub websites) modification. When the user gets a notification, it should show it on the tab of the browser. ([Just like on Quora](http://www.quora.com/).) And even better, would be to get a desktop notification.

In my opinion, it is kind of annoying to just stay at the same page while you could be doing other things.

Comment: Can the down voter please explain why???

Comment: Just to confirm, your talking about things like the inbox messages (ie. replies to questions/comments) and rep/badge acquisition right? as Chat Room already have a setting for getting desktop notifications and if you sit on the index page of a site, most times you'll get (#) in the browser tab when there's been new activity

Comment: Install one of the official apps: iOS app or android app. Both come with cool push notifications. :)

Comment: I'm working on a desktop computer

Comment: I tried copy/paste this code in chrome scripts http://stackapps.com/questions/2362/a-userscript-to-update-the-page-tab-title-with-the-of-unread-notifications, When I run it, I get the following error: "ReferenceError: "document" is not defined."

Comment: FYI: On Meta sites, downvotes are not just to show "quality" of questions, they also mean "I disagree with your *idea* and don't want the feature you are requesting to implement". Although in this case it *could* potentially be someone downvoting because it's a dupe, and to be fair, your question title returns the dupe question in the "Questions that may already have your answer" list. 4th result.